# Parallelizing Fortran nested loops with OpenMP

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, fortran, match, openmp

I have to parallelize with OpenMP a subroutine of a program in Fortran that matches faces in a block structured grid.

Imagine a domain divided in `NBLKS` blocks. Each block is divided in a certain amount of cells -the same amount of cells to every block.
The purpose of this subroutine is to match every face of the boundary cells of every block, so as the program knows we are talking about neighbouring cells -and blocks.

It has 4 nested loops. The first one goes between blocks, then between boundary cell faces -for the given block in the first loop-, and then, looks for the neighbour face cell in all blocks and boundary cells. When it finds it, it writes in an array its position and coordinate. 
For two neighbour blocks there are neighbour cells, that have neighbour faces that are actually the same, so when it finds the match for a given face in block 1, then when the loops goes to block 2 it doesn't look for anything because of the FLAGOC logical that tells wether for a given ID face it has already been match or not.

I have the following issues:

- As I privatized `FLAGOC`, a block doesn't know if there has been a match of any face, and so it works needlessly.
- It is needed to write the `IJLPBK` and `IJRPBK` arrays in order, so as the block 1 faces are first, the block 2 faces second and so on, but as it is assigned different blocks to different threads, maybe the block 4 faces are before the block 2 faces.
- At the moment, the times are greater with the serial program.

I cut the code to make it simplier. The faces coordinates are actually much more complex than this, and have a lot mor variables. Also, when a match is not found a warning is printed.

```
subroutine intfind

c$omp parallel private ( iol, lr, ior, ll, id, nthrds, ijpl, ijpr, xyze, err)
c$omp& firstprivate(flagoc, lnomatch)
c$omp do schedule(static)

do ll=1,nblks
  do iol=iocbk(ll)+1,iocbk(ll)+nocbk(ll)
    if(flagoc(iol)) then
      flagoc(iol)=.false.
      ijpl=ijlpbm(iol)+ijkbk(ll)

      do lr=ll,nblks
        do ior=iocbk(lr)+1,iocbk(lr)+nocbk(lr)
          if(flagoc(ior)) then
            ijpr=ijlpbm(ior) +ijkbk(lr)

check if there is a match

            if(err .eq. 0) then
              flagoc(ior)=.false.
c$omp atomic
              newoc=newoc+1
              ijlpbk(newoc)=ijpl
              ijrpbk(newoc)=ijpr
            endif
          endif
        end do
      end do
    endif
  end do
end do

c$omp end do
c$omp end parallel

return
end
```

Comment: You may have cut the code too much, we can't test it, it is incomplete. See [mcve]. Consider using modern syntax to make it more readable (small caps, free form and so on). The inconsistent indentation does not help, you have `if` and then below you have `do` where from the indentation one would expect an `end if`.

Comment: If you really want to parallelize this and get good performance I suspect you will have to rethink the requirement for ordering you state above, ordering and parallelisation are often incompatible. Otherwise I agree with Vladimir, it's difficult to tell much more from what you have at the moment.